# Connectivity to Oracle from Databricks

Tags: oracle, databricks

I am trying to connect to an Oracle DB from Databricks. However I can not find the exact syntax in any documentation.

Could any one help with exact syntax? Or step by step process for connection establishment?

This is my attempt so far:

```
dbutils.widgets.text("sql_instance_name", "serveraddress")
jdbcHostname = getArgument("sql_instance_name")
jdbcPort = 1521
jdbcDatabase = "secrete"
username = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "masked", key = "username")
password = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "masked", key = "password")
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@jdbcHostname:1521:jdbcDatabase"
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : username,
  "password" : password,
  "driver" : "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The below code snippet shows you how to read in data from an Oracle Database. This method requires that you have the correct driver installed on the cluster.

```
%sql

CREATE TABLE oracle_table
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  dbtable 'table_name',
  driver 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
  user 'username',
  password 'pasword',
  url 'jdbc:oracle:thin://@<hostname>:1521/<db>')
```

Python code to read the data from the database.

```
empDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@//hostname:portnumber/SID") \
    .option("dbtable", "hr.emp") \
    .option("user", "db_user_name") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
    .load()
```

For more details, refer "[Azure Databricks- Data Sources](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/index.html)".

Hope this helps.