# Oracle to Databricks Connection

Tags: oracle, etl, databricks, azure-databricks, cx-oracle

I'm trying to read Oracle Database data on Azure Databricks platform.

Can someone share the step to step process on how I can connect Oracle data to Databricks? I've probably searched the whole internet and read documentation but I can't find a solution that actually works. Not sure if it's because I have the incorrect driver or what.

Here's my process:

- Uploaded the ojdbc8.jar file on the cluster libraries (the instant client 19
- Tried to connect the data on databricks notebook and it didn't work

Can anyone share their process?

- Which jar to upload in the library and where can I find this file?
- How to connect? Sample code?
- Any better way to do this?

Comment: "didn't work" is the most frequent and yet the most useless statement that appears on stack overflow. Please share exactly what you tried, and what the result is, whether an error or unexpected output. I'm now going to google the process and share the link with you.

Comment: Is this what you tried? Did you get an error? Do you have network connectivity to the oracle server from databricks? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405201/connectivity-to-oracle-from-databricks

Comment: Yes that is exactly the code I tried on the link you shared. I wasn't sure if I'm installing the driver right in the first place and I don't think they let me do screenshots here.

Comment: Well.... you answered my first question. That’s a start.

Answer (score 1):

To install library use

```
pip install cx_Oracle
```

Then use below code snippet to read in data from an Oracle database

```
CREATE TABLE oracle_table
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  dbtable 'table_name',
  driver 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
  user 'username',
  password 'pasword',
  url 'jdbc:oracle:thin://@<hostname>:1521/<db>')
```

To read data from oracle database in pyspark you can follow this article -  [Reading Data From Oracle Database With Apache Spark](https://dzone.com/articles/read-data-from-oracle-database-with-apache-spark)

Refer for more information - [Oracle | Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/oracle.html#oracle)

Comment: Yes, but how did you install the driver and where do I get it from?

Comment: @itskcl Its available in Maven central repository. Simply type "com.oracle" in Maven packages section under libraries for a Databricks cluster. The first record that comes up is ojdbc14 and that's what you want.

Comment: Oracle | Databricks link is broken.